# Issues on using multiple where exists statements on HQL

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I had to perform a complex query on Grails Hibernate 4, so I decided to use `HQL`. This is a simplified version of my query (this is already working, without bugs):

```
from AdviceHeader as pa
// ... simple Lvalue where clause starts on this point
where adviceType = 'C'
    and rrType = 'SC'
    and agency.id = :agency
    and branch = :branch
    and str(refNo) like :refNo
    // ... exists where clause starts on this point
    and not exists (
        from AdviceHeader as la, ReportHeader as h
        where h.caRefNo is not null
            and h.caRefNo = la.refNo
            and la.refNo2 = pa.refNo
    )
        // ... another four to five "and not exists" statements
    and not exists (
        from AdviceHeader as laa, AdviceHeader as lab
        where laa.refNo = lab.refNo2
            and laa.refNo = pa.refNo
            and laa.adviceType = 'C'
            and laa.statusCode in ('CL', 'PR')
            and laa.rrType in ('RS')
            and lab.rrType in ('SC')
            group by laa.refNo, laa.amount
            having sum(b.amount) = laa.amount
    )
```

---

The first issue I found is this:

```
            and lab.rrType in ('SC')
            group by laa.refNo, laa.amount
            having sum(b.amount) = laa.amount
    )
    and adviceType = 'C' // A newly added condition
```

when I append another simple clause at the end of the `HQL`, it `throws` an exception:

> **URI:** //branch/retrieveBranches
>
> **Class:** java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> **Message:** null

When at first glance, it should work. I have solved it by placing this new statement between the normal where statement and the `exists` statements

```
    and agency.id = :agency
    and branch = :branch
    and str(refNo) like :refNo
    and adviceType = 'C' // Placed it here instead on the last line
    and not exists (
        from AdviceHeader as la, ReportHeader as h
        where h.caRefNo is not null
```

Why can't I add it on the last part of my `where` clause just like in a normal query? Why should it be added to the middle?

---

My other, more pressing, issue with `HQL` in this scenario is the `order by` clause. I kinda expect, based on the issue above, that it will also throw an error if added at the end of the statement- although I tried it anyway.

```
            and lab.rrType in ('SC')
            group by laa.refNo, laa.amount
            having sum(b.amount) = laa.amount
    )
    order by refNo asc // I added it obviously on the last part
```

But as expected, it also failed. And if I try putting it in the middle, just like what I did above, it throws an error pointing to that misplaced `order by` clause:

> **Class:** QuerySyntaxException
>
> **Message:** GrailsExceptionResolver  - QuerySyntaxException occurred when processing request. unexpected token

After some debugging, I found out that if I really wanted to have the `order by` clause working, I should remove all those `not exists` clauses, and that's a problem. I want to point out that my query is working as expected; what I'm only missing is sorting. Do `exists` and `order by` clause cannot be on one `HQL` statement- some sort of compatibility issue? Is this a known limitation of `HQL`? What's with those `where not exists` statements that kept bugging this and the above query?

---

**Note:** I had already performed tests on all involve Domain classes for obvious errors such as missed mapping, foreign key constraints, identity constraints, and mismatched data type. Simple `findAll()` and `createCriteria()` works fine too. My expected query to run is

```
from AdviceHeader as pa
where adviceType = 'C'
    and rrType = 'SC'
    and agency.id = :agency
    and branch = :branch
    and str(refNo) like :refNo
    and not exists (
        from AdviceHeader as la, ReportHeader as h
        where h.caRefNo is not null
            and h.caRefNo = la.refNo
            and la.refNo2 = pa.refNo
    )
    and not exists (
        from AdviceHeader as laa, AdviceHeader as lab
        where laa.refNo = lab.refNo2
            and laa.refNo = pa.refNo
            and laa.adviceType = 'C'
            and laa.statusCode in ('CL', 'PR')
            and laa.rrType in ('RS')
            and lab.rrType in ('SC')
            group by laa.refNo, laa.amount
            having sum(b.amount) = laa.amount
    )
    and adviceType = 'C' // This should work regardless its position on this where clause
    order by refNo asc // This should only work ON THE LAST PART of the HQL query
```